# Symfony2 production cache error

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I use monolog to receive errors that happens in my symfony application, and every time that some 404 happens I receive the error log in my e-mail.

Its been some time that I receive this same error repeatedly:

> [2013-02-01 10:15:32] request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /cache/65c40e67bd5236d5be8e3637b4c5c61c" (uncaught exception) at {my_path}/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 5179 [] []

Happens with some others routes I have, like "/login/cache/65c40e67bd5236d5be8e3637b4c5c61c"

Well, I don't have any idea why this is happening and I want to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache for prod? Or deleting the cache directory. The latter solved some weird issues I had in the past.

Comment: Yes, I tried to, now I deleted my prod and dev cache folder and cleared the cache (to make recreate this two folders). I'll wait to see if the error will happen again. Thanks @czarpino !

Comment: Well, the error is still happening... Deleted the cache folder and cleared the cache and still the same problem. I`m starting to think it's some serach engine or browser looking for some server cache or something like this... I don't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those issues happen when someone requests `yoururl.com/cache/65c40e67bd5236d5be8e3637b4c5c61c`. As those are http requests, there are most likely tests if you run a specific kind of application to exploid this. There are many scripts which simply crawl the web, doing some http requests to every domain they can find and if they get a certain kind of response, they try some more.

If you don't want to get those kind of errors with monolog, you could change the level to `critical`. There is no way right now to change the level of those 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about crawlers, but I needed to be sure about this. I'll keep the level as it is, it can be useful some times.